# Number of ways of forming subsets satisfying the given condition below

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a set $S$ of total elements being $"N"$ , we are taking two random subsets from the set S , called them $P$ and $Q$ .       Totals ways of choosing those subsets such that we have

- A) n($P$ $\cup$ $Q$) = $d$ where $d \in [1,N]$.
- B) n($P$ $\cap$ $Q$) = b where $b \in [1,N]$ .

> For A part what i considered was taking case of having no element common , then 1 element common etc till all elements common but for that i need the second part answer as b varies . But i am stuck on how to get the required Ways For B part.

Comment: As a way to get started:  I suggest computing the number of ways to choose $P,Q$ such that $P\cap Q=\emptyset$.

Comment: Yeah i did that @lulu , for that we just have to choose elements lets say k out of N in P and then any of the remaining 0 to N-k to the other one , which gives value as 3^n

Comment: So, the general (specified) intersection is no harder.  If $T$ is some specified subset, then you just need to choose two random subsets of the complement of $T$ in $S$.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "two *disjoint* random subsets of the complement of $T$ in $S$".

Comment: Are you trying to satisfy Conditions A and B simultaneously, or are these separate problems?

Comment: Thanks understood your method @lulu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem we can split it in two, first getting d elements from S and then splitting this elements in $3$, the ones belonging to $P,Q$ and $P \cap Q$, with $|P \cap Q| = b$.

The number of ways of choosing d elements from a set of cardinal $N$ is ${N \choose d}$. The number of ways to split d elements in $3$ disjoint sets such that $|P \cap Q| = b$ is ${d \choose b} \cdot 2^{d-b}$, since for each element that doesn't belong to $P \cap Q$ we have $2$ options.

Therefore we have that we can choose sets $P$ and $Q$ that satisfy both $A$ and $B$ in ${N \choose d} \cdot {d \choose b} \cdot 2^{d-b}$ different ways.